# Can API.AI scale well for a large enterprise?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es

As the title suggests, I'd like to know if API.AI can sustain an exponentially increasing number of requests.

Let's say there is 10k requests per second, will it be able to handle that?

Besides that, is there a good way to store the ever increasing number of intents? To ensure the console browser is neat and not cluttered.

From what I see now, the only approach is to create multiple agents of different categories so that intents can be easily classified and managed, but how can I assign which agents to use in my bot codes?

Appreciate if anyone can provide some thoughts on those 3 questions.